# Azure Pipeline run protractor test - chrome version mismatched

Tags: azure, yaml, protractor, azure-pipelines

How do we set up yml to always match chrome version and chrome driver version?
It was working well since I set up early this year. Just got this error on pipeline.

```html
[20:37:00] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 95
Current browser version is 94.0.4606.81 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
```

Here is my yml file look like.

```html
pool:
  vmImage: "VS2017-Win2016"
  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: "node webdriver-manager update"
    inputs:
      script: "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update"
      workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/folderdirectory

  - task: CmdLine@2
    displayName: "node webdriver-manager start"
    inputs:
      script: "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start --detach"
      workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/folderdirectory
 - script: npx protractor conf.js
```

Comment: Hi Allison; can I ask where you're running your pipeline? i.e. is it on a hosted agent or a self-hosted agent?

Comment: Use the selenium docker containers and to run the tests and you won't have this problem. The images are locked to a specific version of the browser and drivers. Lock the image to a specific version in the yml instead of latest and you will practically never see this error again. Only time I think it would be an issue is if you upgrade to a later version of protractor that is not supported by whichever browser version you are using.